# check if a string in a list is a subset of another string in the same list

Tags: python

I am working on a python script with a list of strings. I want to create a method that takes in a list of strings and returns a list of supersets and removes the subsets. Consider the below case:

```
A = ['this is a sentence', 'who is alice', 'sentence', 'hi i am carrot', 'i am carrot']
```

Now if you see the `array A`, it has two elements that are a pair superset and subset, `'this is a sentence'` is a superset of `'sentence'` and similarly `'hi i am carrot'` and  `'i am carrot'` I want to write a function that removes the subsets from the list and returns the updated list.

In the above example the output would look like:

```
ResultA = ['this is a sentence', 'who is alice', 'hi i am carrot']
```

I've written a quick code sample that can showcase what I am looking for but the I am not sure if using two `for` loops is the right way:

```
elements_to_keep = []
for i in phase_two_match:
    for j in phase_two_match:
        if i == j:
            continue
        else:
            if j not in i:
                elements_to_keep.append(j)
```

Comment: Variable names in python are normally `snake_case`. So `ResultA` should be `result_a`.

Comment: iterate over both lists and remove if "sentence".find("blabla") != -1

Comment: @AlekseiMaide "blabla" in "sentence" is preferred to `find()` since you don't need the index

Comment: The order is of no significance.

Comment: The string method `endswith()` may be helpful to you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/568785/bailey-parker yes, you are right, the find() was first that popped into mind, but obviously "in" is more pythonic.

Comment: @BaileyParker this is just a mockup of the actual question so the variable names are just there to explain the problem instead of actual variable names

Comment: How can you tell which is the subset and superset if they both have equal length. Example: `this has four words` and `tis have four points` which one would you keep?

Comment: Also what happen to `who is alice` isn't `is` a subset of `this is a sentence`?

Comment: @MooingRawr both of them as neither of them are subsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(A) if all(i==idx or x not in elem for idx, elem in enumerate(A))]
```

This builds a list of those items in `A` that for each item in `A` either share an index with that item (i.e. are the same item) or are not a substring of that item.

Answer (score 2):

This return items from `A` that are not `in` another item in `A`, but skips instances where the items are exact matches (ie: skip itself)

```
[x for x in A if not any(x in y and x!=y for y in A)]
# returns:
['this is a sentence', 'who is alice', 'hi i am carrot']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is following(although not the most efficient):

```
def myFunc(A):
    duplicate_index = []
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        score = [1 if a in b else 0 for b in A]
        if sum(score) > 1:
            duplicate_index.append(i)
    return [c for i, c in enumerate(A) if i not in duplicate_index]
```